# What happens when we use "callback" in a function ? and when do we need to use it?

Tags: web3js, transactions, javascript

**What happens** when we use "`callback`" as a *keyword* in a function ?  And **when** do we need to use it ? and what happens if we do not use it ? For example in the following JavaScript code:

```
function signPayment(recipient, amount, nonce, contractAddress, callback) {
  var hash = "0x" + ethereumjs.ABI.soliditySHA3(
    ["address", "uint256", "uint256", "address"],
    [recipient, amount, nonce, contractAddress]
  ).toString("hex");

  web3.personal.sign(hash, web3.eth.defaultAccount, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Callback basically is a function which is passed to other function and executed there when you call this "callback". Very simple example can be found on [mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).
If you don't pass any callback, depending on function code it may or may not affect your program, since callback will be null.

Answer (score 1):

Some web3 methods are asynchronous and require a callback.

The callback function is executed once the original function is done and takes a transaction hash or similar as an argument.

You can avoid callbacks entirely by using an async/await pattern.

For instance:

```
async function signPayment(recipient, amount, nonce, contractAddress) {
  var hash = "0x" + ethereumjs.ABI.soliditySHA3(
    ["address", "uint256", "uint256", "address"],
    [recipient, amount, nonce, contractAddress]
  ).toString("hex");

  var signed = await web3.personal.sign(hash, web3.eth.defaultAccount);
  console.log(signed);
}
```

Comment: @async @Maxpeinas Thank you. Is there any advantages for each of approaches : `callback` vs. `async` ? Thanks

Comment: async still does a callback under the hood, so there is no difference, except that using async makes your code simpler

Comment: See this for a comparison between async/await and callbacks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336029/javascript-async-await-vs-promise-callback

Comment: Thank you. Just, I need to run this JavaScript code to sign a payment by signPayment function (Full code is [Here](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/23/writing-a-simple-payment-channel/)). So, I saved the JavaScript code in a `.js` file (You can see the content of this `.js` file [Here](https://ibb.co/dSq0jy).) However, when I run this file by `node filename.js` I receive the error message that I uploaded the screen shot [Here](https://ibb.co/hKb1rd). I do not know where I am going wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: @sas Check out this gist: https://gist.github.com/Kaisle/bece5cbdcac17385d2f8e0cfa7c6b095. Just replace the arguments with the arguments from your code (and ignore the callback argument, you don't need it)

Comment: Thank you, now I receive an error related to `ethereumjs-abi`. [Here](https://ibb.co/gPMzcJ) is the content of the file that I run it. And [Here](https://ibb.co/bGdqjy) is the error message that i receive. Btw, when I want to install `ethereumjs-abi` that is used in this code, I receive [this message](https://ibb.co/jJH5HJ). I am not sure if it's properly installed. Thanks

Comment: Have you included the dependency in your file using require('ethereumjs-abi') or similar?

Comment: Thanks you, yeah I'd forgotten ... but now I added `var abi = require('ethereumjs-abi')` in top of the code ([HERE ](https://ibb.co/imjwPy)). However, I receive the same error ([HERE ](https://ibb.co/bWvWrd)) Thanks

Comment: try the following: var ethereumjs = require('ethereumjs-abi');

Comment: Good now it's recognized .... but I receive new error :  [HERE ](https://ibb.co/jZbonJ) (`soliditySHA3`) Thanks again

Comment: try without ABI: ethereumjs.solidityShA3

Comment: Thank you, it's solved but a new one ... hope it's the last one .... [HERE](https://ibb.co/m52YMd) (`sign`) I also added `Web3 = require("web3")` and `web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));` Thanks again

Comment: I used `web3.eth.personal.sign` instead of `web3.personal.sign` and `sign` is solved, but the new error is HERE: https://ibb.co/gAG2gd Thank again

Comment: it's not because of `web3.eth.defaultAccount` ? We do not need to initiate `defaultAccount` value ? Thanks